# How to Import past history into new git repo

Tags: git, github, history

I have a lot of old scripts I want to import into GitHub. I’m wondering if there is a way to add history that happened before the git started tracking the changes.

**What is happening now:**
I make a repo on Github or a local git. I add the old script files to it and it looks like I just created the file in git, but the file could have been originally created several years ago.

**Example file**

```
!/bin/bash
# <date> created this script to do this
# yyyymmdd added feature 
# yyyymmdd fixed something
```

I was tracking my changes in the heading of the file I was updating. Is there a way to add the version control information on in the new git repo?

If there is s better way to add the old script’s history let me know.

Comment: Can you clarify? I have no idea what you are trying to do. Do you want to import old commits of a different repo? Do you want to insert a single commit before existing commits? Are you asking if you can (magically) get old versions of a non-version-controlled file back?

Comment: You answered yourself: "... before the git started tracking the changes."

Comment: @knittl Before using git or any other version control application, I would manually put the info information into the heading of my scripts. That is what I as trying to show. Is there a way to add this old version control information into the git repo?

Comment: @Cyberninja but where do you keep the old content of the script? Or are you only interested in "commit messages" and don't care about the actual content? You cannot construct old versions of your file out of thin air.

Comment: @knittl I just had the scripts in my home directory. When I switched jobs or computers I would just but them on Google Drive. 

Oh, updated the question. I hope you understand it better now

Comment: @Cyberninja let me rephrase my comment: You have commits A-B-C and want to end up with Z-A-B-C with commit Z containing the latest version of your script file?

Comment: @knittl I'm sorry your not understanding me. I have a script that has been around for a few years. Now I want to migrate this project to git. So I have history or commits  A-B-C, now I want D and and any future commits to be tracked by git, instead of the old method. 


I'M currently reading this: https://docs.github.com/en/migrations/overview/planning-your-migration-to-github  In this document it states that a Migration origin can be from a network share. Which is exactly where I'm at.

Comment: @Cyberninja it's still unclear. Do you want to add the latest/current content of this script or do you expect Git to be able to somehow reconstruct earlier versions of this file? If you have not used version control on this file before, there's no way to get older versions of it, because there only is a single version available. The migration guide is from one code-hosting platform to a different code-hosting platform (and doesn't really have to do with Git, but with GitHub only)

Comment: @knittl I want to add old scripts to git. I then want to be able to make it know in git that this script was made before it came under git control. I don't need git to give me older versions, I already have that. I just want to switch it git for all future commits. In the link I sent you it says what I'm trying to do is possible. You are over thinking it.

Comment: @Cyberninja if you have multiple old versions of the script, create a new repo, add each version to a new commit. Then merge this history into your other repo or graft/rebase your existing repo on top of the "reconstructed history". Would that solve your use case?

Comment: @knittl Yeah that sounds reasonable, but I don't want old scripts to appear in GitHub as newly written scripts. That is why I want the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with a single repo only, but using two separate repositories in the process makes it easier and provides less chance for error.

First, create a new, empty Git repo and add your file(s):

```
git init old-history
cd old-history
# copy your file, make sure you use the expected directory structure
git add your_file
git commit -m 'adding file' # optionally specify --date=... if you require that
# change file content / add more files / create more commits, as desired
# note down the commit id of the last commit! (git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Once you have that, it is time to graft the two repositories together:

```
git remote add existing ../path/to/your/existing/new-repo
git fetch existing
# find the root commit of your existing repo (assuming a "master" branch):
root="$(git log --oneline existing/master | tail -1)"
# replace the root commit with a commit that links both histories:
git replace --graft "$root" "$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
```

At this point, when you run `git log` or `gitk`, you should see the grafted history that looks like your scripts were always part of the repo.

Ultimately, you want to persist the grafted history with `git filter-branch`. Please note that this will change the commit hashes of *all commits of your existing repo*!

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Finally, push the rewritten history pack to your existing repo/upstream or fetch the rewritten history. If this repo was shared, everybody with a clone (and you, if you had multiple clones of the same repo) needs to throw away their local version and replace it with the new, rewritten history.

Comment: Wow, you put in a lot of effort. I will give it a try and let you know. Thank you